# Javascript delays the page load time and corrupts the results in google page speed insigt

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have a section for entering the address in the text field with hints from google, javascript on the home page, which is responsible for transferring address coordinates to a web application on another page, but in my case on the same hosting and domain

the script delays the page load time very much and corrupts the results in google page speed insight

Can someone suggest how to solve it?

here is the script on the home page:

```
<script>

        function go_form() {
            var address = document.querySelector('input[name="your-name"]').value;
            const lat = search.lat();
            const lng = search.lng();
            window.location.assign("Https:........... ?code=" + address + "&lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng);

        }
    
</script>

    <script>
        document.querySelector('input[name="your-name"]').addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

        function keyDownTextField(e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode;
            console.log(keyCode);
            if (keyCode == 13) {
                go_form();
            }
        }
    </script>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCWlUs26-eUz0JURkuGLHy8_RJl0DBTLOo&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
            <script>
        var search = null;

        function initMap() {
            var input = document.querySelector("input[name='your-name']");
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function () {
                var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
                search = places [0].geometry.location;
            });
            input.placeholder = "";
        }
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the script on a separate file and load it asynchronously:

```
<script src="path-to-script.js" defer><script>
```

or

```
<script src="path-to-script.js" async><script>
```

(the fastest solution is to use defer in the : https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/ )

If the order is important (if you want to load the maps first) only use defer.

Comment: Well if i use defer attribute with these scripts,it does not load then,sometimes it load with delay sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately does not solve the problem, does anyone else have a solution>

the main page is here:

itrenhold.no

there is a section for entering an address in the text field next to the address "bestill_na"